# Ler um arquivo csv e adicionar seus dados em um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x, dicionário

Eu tenho um código onde terei uma função que irá passar os dados de um arquivo csv para um dicionário. O processo será pegar os filmes com suas respectivas notas e adcionar a um dicionário relativo a cada usuário, e adcionar esses dicionários a um dicionário principal.

```
import csv

path = 'C:\\Users\\Rafael\\Desktop\\DataMining\\RECOMMENDATION\\Movie_Ratings.csv'
data = {}

def loadCSV():
    file = open(path, newline='')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(reader)
    header.remove('')
    n = 0  
    for u in header:
        n += 1
        data[u] = {}
        for line in reader:
            data[u][line[0]] = line[n]
loadCSV()
print(data)
```

Porém, ao rodar meu código...

```
{'Patrick C': {'Alien': '', 'Avatar': '4', 'Blade Runner': '5', 'Braveheart': '4', 'Dodgeball': '5', 'Forest Gump': '4', 'Gladiator': '', 'Jaws': '', 'Kazaam': '2', 'Lord of the Rings': '4', 'Napolean Dynamite': '3', 'Old School': '3', 'Pootie Tang': '', 'Pulp Fiction': '', 'Scarface': '', 'Shawshank Redemption': '5', 'Snakes on a Plane': '4', 'Spiderman': '4', 'Star Wars': '5', 'The Dark Knight': '4', 'The Happening': '1', 'The Matrix': '3', 'Toy Story': '4', 'Village': '', 'You Got Mail': '1'}, 'Heather': {}, 'Bryan': {}, 'Patrick T': {}, 'Thomas': {}, 'aaron': {}, 'vanessa': {}, 'greg': {}, 'brian': {}, 'ben': {}, 'Katherine': {}, 'Jonathan': {}, 'Zwe': {}, 'Erin': {}, 'Chris': {}, 'Zak': {}, 'Matt': {}, 'Josh': {}, 'Amy': {}, 'Valerie': {}, 'Gary': {}, 'Stephen': {}, 'Jessica': {}, 'Jeff': {}}
```

...Somente o primeiro usuário recebe as notas dos filmes. Por favor HELP!!

Comment: **Matheus**, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/328146/edit) sua pergunta e coloque um exemplo de como está a estrutura do arquivo *Movie_Ratings.csv*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como não foi informado a estrutura do CSV, vou assumir que o mesmo está estruturado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A leitura de um arquivo é sempre incremental, quando **csv.reader()** é chamado, o retorno é um iterador e não uma lista. Nesse caso, o iterador  funciona usando um contador interno para acessar as linhas do arquivo, se o arquivo tem 100 linhas, quando o for termina de ser executado o contador vai estar em 100, porém se você tentar executar outro for, o contador vai começar em 100 e não do 0, por isso que apenas o primeiro usuário possui avaliações.

Então para ler os dados do arquivo, o código precisa ser alterado dessa forma:

```
import csv

path = 'C:\\Users\\Rafael\\Desktop\\DataMining\\RECOMMENDATION\\Movie_Ratings.csv'
data = []

def loadCSV():
    file = open(path, newline='')
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(reader)
    header.remove('')

    for line in reader:
        item = {
            "filme": "",
            "avaliacoes": []
        }

        for index, valor in enumerate(line):
            if index == 0:
                # Primeiro item da lista = nome do filme
                item["filme"] = valor
            else:
                # Demais itens = avaliacao de usuario
                """
                Como o nome do usuario ta no header, na mesma sequencia
                em que os itens são acessados, basta passar o index - 1,
                para saber de quem foi a nota
                """
                item["avaliacoes"].append({
                    "usuario": header[index - 1],
                    "nota": valor
                })

        data.append(item)

loadCSV()
print(data)
```

O resultado do código acima aparece assim:

```
[
  {
    "filme": "Alien",
    "avaliacoes": [
      {
        "usuario": "Patrick C",
        "nota": 1
      },
      {
        "usuario": "Heather",
        "nota": 2
      },
      {
        "usuario": "Bryan",
        "nota": 3
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "filme": "Avatar",
    "avaliacoes": [
      {
        "usuario": "Patrick C",
        "nota": 3
      },
      {
        "usuario": "Heather",
        "nota": 2
      },
      {
        "usuario": "Bryan",
        "nota": 1
      },
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Cara tu ajudou com meu problema, já estou até usando a sua resolução aqui. Porém o que me intriga é: porque não funcionou antes? Foi erro no MEU código? Porque funcionou no primeiro usuário, mas não funfou no segundo.

Comment: Acontece que a leitura de um arquivo é sempre incremental, quando csv.reader() é chamado, o retorno é um iterador e não uma lista. Nesse caso, o interador  funciona usando um contador interno, se o arquivo tem 100 linhas, quando ele termina de ler a primeira vez o contador tá em 100, porém se você tentar fazer outro for, o contador vai começar em 100 e não do 0, por isso que apenas o primeiro usuário tem avaliações.

Comment: Putz, não sabia disso, muitissimo obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O seu código não funcionou porque você está tentando repetir a leitura do arquivo:

```
for u in header:
    # ...
    for line in reader:
```

Da primeira vez vai funcionar, porém da segunda, `reader` já foi consumido. Pro seu código funcionar como está, você teria que "rebobinar" o arquivo, ou armazenar o conteúdo em uma lista.